# dividing two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to divide two complex numbers, namely:$$z = 2\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right)\right)$$ and $$w = \left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)\right)$$

I'm trying to figure out the following:  $\frac{\overline z}{6w}$.

The way I've done it is figuring the conjugate of $z$ which is $\overline z = 2\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right)\right)$ if I'm not mistaken.
But now I'm sort of stuck, I tried to divide it by simply dividing $\frac{2}{6}$ and substracting the argument from the $\cos$ and $\sin$ of $\overline z$ but I didn't get anywhere for figuring out $e^{\theta i}$ which would be (according to the answer)  $\frac{2}{6} = r$ and $e^{\theta i} = \frac{73\pi}{55}$.

I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: The conjugate of $e^{i\theta}$ is just $e^{-i\theta}$, since $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Euler's formula, we can write $$z=2e^{\frac{3\pi i}{11}}, w=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$$ So $$\overline z=2e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{11}}$$ and then we can simplify it to $$\frac{\overline z}{6w}=\frac{2e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{11}}}{6e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}}=\frac{e^{i\pi(\frac{-3}{11}-\frac{2}{5})}}{3}=\frac{e^{i\pi(\frac{-37}{55})}}{3}$$

Adding $2\pi$ to the argument yields $\frac{e^{i\pi\frac{73}{55}}}{3}$, so $r=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\theta=\frac{73\pi}{55}$

Comment: Using $\exp(x)$ instead of $e^{x}$ makes the fractions more legible.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future :)